# find element inside array of dictionaries for a given value

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have two NSArray variables, each one of then gets a similar NSDictionary inside.

For a given row (indexPath.row):

```
 NSArray* array1 = ...;
 NSDictionary* item = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 int myid = [[item valueForKey:@"id"] intValue];
 // id = 5
```

Now I need to find the element with id = 5 in array2, but because I'm a c# developer, I think it is a little weird to use a for to do that.

Is there any alternatives to a for?

Comment: How a `for()` loop is even related to this problem? What you have so far is just fine. Except that you should really not use `id` as a variable name in Objective-C as it's a type name for a generic object type.

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear. I have to find the id 5 in the second array.

Comment: So you want to find the dictionary in `array2` of which the value corresponding to the `id` key is also 5?

Comment: Yep! My bad if I'm not clear. English is not my first language.

Comment: no problem, neither is it for me. Well, a for loop is not a bad solution in this case, why do you think it's weird?

Comment: I think it is weird because in c# we do that in a one line linq query (I know that a linq query is, essentially, a for loop). Is there any alternatives in iOS?

Comment: What type does [item valueForKey:@"id"] have? It is important so I can give you the solution. Is it NSString?

Comment: @Daniel if it responds to `intValue` it's presumably an NSString or NSNumber.

Comment: @lolol however, see Martin R's solution, it's also a loop (internally), but it's rather elegant.

Comment: Can not be int.
This might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697749/testing-if-nsmutablearray-contains-a-string-object

Comment: No, it does not. I have a dictionary inside each position of the array, and what I need to compare is a particular element of the dictionary.

Comment: @H2CO3 yeh, I'm gonna use it, thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NSArray` has a method `indexOfObjectPassingTest` which you can use:

```
NSArray *array2 = ...;
int searchId = ...;
NSUInteger index2 = [array2 indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(NSDictionary *item, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    BOOL found = [[item objectForKey:@"id"] intValue] == searchId;
    return found;
}];

if (index2 != NSNotFound) {
    // First matching item at index2.
} else {
    // No matching item found.
}
```

This returns the first matching index. If you need all matching indexes, use `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest`.

Comment: It works, nice code. When the value is not found it gives me the int max value.

Comment: @lolol: Yes, it returns `NSNotFound` if item was found. `NSNotFound` is `LONG_MAX`, which is the same as `INT_MAX` on a 32-bit architecture. I will update the answer accordingly.